# Mysql select data with sub-select from one table about user sequencing: first decline, after completed in same month

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, self-join

I have table 'campaign' with fields

id - campaign_id

user_id - id of user

created_at - date of campaign creation

status (declined or completed) - campaign status (after moderator review)

I have to calculate the user amount who was firstly declined by the administrator and another column calculate the amount of users who made another campaign and complete it in the same months after the decline. And finally, calculate the conversion rate of the month

table example

```
id / user_id / created_at / status
1 / 1244 / 2020-01-01 / declined
2 / 1244 / 2020-01-20 / completed
3 / 1467 / 2020-01-02 / declined
4 / 1467 / 2020-02-01 / completed
5 / 3567 / 2020-02-02 / decline
6 / 3567 / 2020-02-04 / completed
7 / 5689 / 2020-02-27 / decline
8 / 3567 / 2020-02-28 / completed
```

expected result group by month columns year, month, amount users with the decline, amount users with complete after the decline, conversion

```
year / month / decline_users / complet_after_decl_users / conv.

2020 / 1 / 2 / 1 / 50

2020 / 2 / 2 / 1 / 50
```

If user made more then one completed after decline - we had to count only first complete after decline (cause distinct cases)

Query example

```
SELECT
    year(c.created_at),
    month(c.created_at),
    count(distinct(c.user_id)),
    count(distinct(com.comp_user)),
    count(distinct(com.comp_user))/count(distinct(c.user_id)) * 100
FROM campaign c
JOIN 
    (SELECT
        c.id,
        c.user_id as 'comp_user',
        c.created_at as 'compe_date'
    FROM campaign c
    WHERE c.status = 'completed'
    ) com
    ON c.user_id = com.comp_user
WHERE c.status = 'declined'
AND com.compe_date > c.created_at
AND month(com.compe_date) = month(c.created_at)
AND year(com.compe_date) = year(c.created_at)
GROUP BY year(c.created_at),  month(c.created_at)
```

Another try

```
select month(t1.created_at) month, t1.total_completed, t2.total_declined, (t1.total_completed/t2.total_declined)*100 as conversion 
from 
(
 Select c1.created_at, count(distinct c1.user_id) total_completed from campaign c1
 left Join 
 (
  select user_id, max(created_at) date_declined from campaign
  where status = 'declined'
  group by user_id
 ) c2
 on c2.user_id = c1.user_id

 left join
 (
  select user_id, max(created_at) date_completed 
  from campaign
  where status = 'completed'
  group by user_id
 ) c3
 on c3.user_id = c1.user_id

 where datediff(date_completed, date_declined) > 0
 and year(date_completed) = year(date_declined)
 and month(date_completed) = month(date_declined)
 and year(c1.created_at) = 2020
 group by month(c1.created_at)
) t1

join 
(
 Select created_at, count(distinct user_id) total_declined
 from campaign
 where status = 'declined'
  and year(created_at) = 2020
 group by month(created_at)
) t2

on year(t1.created_at) = year(t2.created_at)
and month(t1.created_at) = month(t2.created_at)
```

Comment: Your sample data and expected result doesn't match. There are only three rows for January and one for February, yet you have counts of 350 or 400, respectively... It is also not clear "how far" a "decline" reaches. If a user was "decline" at one time and "completed" more than one time *n* afterwards, does that counts as one or *n*? You should [edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: @stickybit thanks for your comment - I've made edits. hope answer for all your questions.

Comment: @stickybit could you please help with the query?